# Files easily opened with IE, do not always open with Firefox ("Content corrupted")

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Users of my app can view files uploaded by some other users by clicking a link to this file. Returning a file response is done in MVC like this:

```
public ActionResult GetFile(int id)
        {
            Attachment attachment = applicationService.GetAttachment(id);
            HttpContext.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = attachment.MimeType;
            HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + attachment.FileName + "\"");

            return File(attachment.FileContent, attachment.MimeType, attachment.FileName);
        }
```

Nothing fancy. It always works in IE, it does not always work in Firefox. Firefox for some files says "Content corrupted" even though IE opens it without problems.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

probably by this time you already fix your problem, 
I found this code that could help you check what are you doing different, I have not tried it yet, test it and let us know if it worked for you or please post your solution:

```
private static void WriteFile(string fileName, string contentType, string content)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    context.Response.Charset = "";
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
    context.Response.Write(content);
    context.Response.End();
 }
```

regards.

source [http://stephenwalther.com](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/16/asp-net-mvc-tip-2-create-a-custom-action-result-that-returns-microsoft-excel-documents.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this as well

```
    byte[] bytes = // get byte array for the file
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "mimeType Here";
    Response.AddHeader(
      "Content-Disposition",
      string.Format("attachment; filename={0}",filename)
    );
    // stream pdf bytes to the browser
    Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    Response.End();
```

If you know already have a file then you could just use

```
    Response.TransmitFile((fileLocation));
```

in place of OutputStream.Write

Hope this helps.